# unknown attribute with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism

In my online shop I have tables **Product** and **Size**, also I think I need to add a table **Restocking**

Instead of updating a product,  I guess It's better to have  a **Restocking** table then I could track the dates where I added any new sizes, quantity, and why not the new prices (buying and selling)... and create stats...

Do you this it is correct?

Once a **Restocking** is created, the corresponding Product is updated with new quantity and price?

Well,

So it started this way:

```
#Product 
has_many :sizes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sizes, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

#Size 
belongs_to :product
```

The **Restocking table** needs to have sizes attributes (like product)

I believe that I have to use polymorphic associations, but how I am supposed to update my schema , what should I add, remove?

So since I added the **Restocking** model, my models look like this:

```
#Product
has_many :sizes, inverse_of: :product,  dependent: :destroy, as: :sizeable
has_many :restockings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sizes, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

#Restocking
has_many :sizes, as: :sizeable
belongs_to :product
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sizes, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true


#Size
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :restocking
belongs_to :sizeable, polymorphic: true, class_name: "Size"
```

schema.rb

```
 create_table "sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "size_name"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.bigint "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "quantity_stock"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_sizes_on_product_id"
  end


  create_table "restockings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "product_id"
    t.bigint "sizeable_id"
    t.decimal "price", precision: 10, scale: 2
    t.decimal "buying_price", precision: 10, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_restockings_on_product_id"
    t.index ["sizeable_id"], name: "index_restockings_on_sizeable_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", limit: 150, null: false
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "color"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.json "attachments"
    t.string "brand"
    t.string "ref"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.decimal "buying_price", precision: 10, scale: 2
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id"
  end
```

At this point I have several errors, like

in ProductsController

```
    def new
      @product = Product.new
      @product.sizes.build
    end
```

error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError at /admin/products/new
unknown attribute 'sizeable_id' for Size.
```

Can you light me on the migrations I have to change? 
Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there, to use polymorphic inside your `Size` model, you have to change the **size resource**, and add two attributes to the resource: `sizeable_id` and `sizeable_type`.

The `sizeable_type` is a string, indicates the class of the parent element, in your case, can be `Product` or `Restocking`, and `sizeable_id` indicates the `element_id` to find the parent element, your relations are correct, but you must add this elements to your `Size`, see the following:

One exemple of a migration to your case:

```
class AddSizeableToSize < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :sizes, :sizeable, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end
```

On your `Size` model:

```
# app/models/size.rb

class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sizeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

In your `Product` or `Restocking` model:

```
has_many :sizes, as: :sizeable
```

This is just a simple way to make your case works! If you want to know more about rails associations and polymorphism, can take a look in this [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: hum sorry not sure it worth a new question, when I create a new product or when i create a new restocking  I have this error: `Validation failed: Sizes product must exist, Sizes restocking must exist`
Is there anything missing ? See the schema?

Comment: removes the `belongs_to :product` and `belongs_to :restocking` from your `Size` model, and keeps only the `belongs_to :sizeable, polymorphic: true`

Comment: glad i can help